# What is the maximum number of electrons that can be found in an atom when its last electron has the following quantum numbers?

Tags: electronic-configuration

The question is as follows:

> What is the maximum number of electrons that can be found in an atom when its last electron has the following quantum numbers: $n=4, m_{l}=+3$

Since $m_{l}=+3$ I know that $l=3$ and then I wrote them all:
$$1s^2, 2s^2, 2p^6, 3s^2, 3p^6, 4s^2, 3d^{10}, 4p^6, 5s^2, 4d^{10}, 5p^6, 6s^2, 4f^{14}$$
which means that the maximum number of electrons is $70$, but the actual configuration in the answer was:
$$1s^2, 2s^2, 2p^6, 3s^2, 3p^6, 4s^2, 3d^{10}, 4p^6, 5s^2, 4d^{10}, 5p^6, 6s^2, 5d^1, 4f^{14}$$
which means that the maximum number of electrons is 71. What didn't I count for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the electron configurations of the relevant elements:

[image]

Source: https://chemistrytheperiodictable.files.wordpress.com/2017/11/electronic-config-lanthanides.png?w=474&h=399

The first $f$ electrons get filled in the 6th period of the table of elements. First, the $6s$ get filled, then (for lanthanum) the $5d$ gets filled for the first time, and then the $4f$ subshell. As you go across the lanthanides, the $5d$ is sometimes filled with one electron and sometimes empty.

> What is the maximum number of electrons that can be found in an atom when its last electron has the following quantum numbers: n=4,ml=+3

The answer depend on how you interpret "last electron". Going from Thulium to Ytterbium, you could argue the last electron is going into $4f$, whereas from Ytterbium to Lutetium, the last electron is going to $5d$. On the other hand, the $5d$ is filled before $5f$ going from Barium to Lanthanum. Comparing Lanthanum to Lutetium, all 14 electrons seem to be going into the $4f$ subshell, supporting the notion that the answer to the question is 71.

In the end, it is not the best question - it does not have a clear answer, and you don't really learn anything from the answer other than that the energies of $4f$ and $5d$ are close to each other.